# BS4, Figuring out if .text is empty

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a webpage. In a certain case where all the data is there it works, however when a user is 'qualifying' it returns a 400 error. I am trying to figure out how to tell if the text is empty.

Here is the HTML:

https://hastebin.com/abotejaquy.scala -- As you can see most of the tags have text in them ("Silver IV") but two of them have nothing.

Here is my code that I am trying:

https://hastebin.com/xubibivara.py

It returns this:

Silver III

Silver II

Silver IV

(Space where qualifying should be)

Silver I

Silver III

Silver III

(Space where qualifying should be)

Silver V

Silver IV

-- The text shows up but the qualifying doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your particular problem, but a rule of thumb for the **first draft** of the code - if something raises an exception, you can just handle the exception. That is especially true for the scrapers.

Take a look at the code below:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

```
request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
all_tags = list(soup.find_all('div', class_='profile-ranking-rank'))
kitname = list(soup.find_all('div', class_="profile-ranking-title"))

for tag in all_tags:
    try:
       print (tag.text)
    except Exception:
       print("Qualifying")
```

**UPDATE**

I can't reproduce the exception, but it looks like some spans have empty strings in them. The way BS4 handles it is to have `.text` as an empty string, not None, so you should check for the string length in this case:

```
request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.content, 'html.parser')
all_tags = list(soup.find_all('div', class_='profile-ranking-rank'))
kitname = list(soup.find_all('div', class_="profile-ranking-title"))

for tag in all_tags:
    if len(tag.text) > 0:
       print (tag.text)
    else:
       print("Qualifying")
```

Comment: Since Python considers empty strings as `False`, you can replace `if len(tag.text) > 0:` with `if tag.text:`

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. :-)